# Why does 1.asInstanceOf[T] not throw ClassCastException?

Tags: scala

```
scala> def g[T] = 1.asInstanceOf[T]
g: [T]=> T

scala> g[String]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  ... 32 elided

scala> { g[String]; 1 }
res0: Int = 1
```

But:

```
scala> def f = 1.asInstanceOf[String]
f: String

scala> { f; 1 }
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  at .f(<console>:7)
  ... 32 elided
```

What is the logic here? How do I trigger `ClassCastException` in a type parametric function?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any@asInstanceOf[T0]:T0

Comment: But I'm casting to `String`, not a parametric type. The comment in the Scala documentation about type erasure doesn't obviously apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning answers my question:

```
scala> def g[T] = 1.isInstanceOf[T]
<console>:7: warning: abstract type T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       def g[T] = 1.isInstanceOf[T]
                                ^
```

So `asInstanceOf[T]` is a compile-time cast. It has no effect at run-time. In the case where I got the `ClassCastException` it was raised not by `asInstanceOf[T]` but by the actual conversion that happened outside of the function.

The solution is to take a `ClassTag` and use `classTag[T].runtimeClass.cast`. This behaves slightly differently though: you can use `asInstanceOf[Double]` on an `Int`, but `cast` will fail with a `ClassCastException`. The solution to this problem then is to use Apache `commons-lang`'s [`ClassUtils.isAssignable`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#isAssignable%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29).

Comment: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast Java reflection is not Scala reflection. For type safety, use TypeTag. ClassTag lets you create arrays. It depends what you're trying to accomplish safely.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Shapeless! Looks very interesting. But I don't quite get the other comment. How would I do this with a TypeTag?

Comment: You want to avoid losing type safety, so pass in the type tag `def g[T : TypeTag]`

Comment: But then what do I do with the TypeTag?

Comment: The usual things like `<:<` conformance of types http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi and http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags