# How scala type conversion works?

Tags: scala, casting, classcastexception

I am trying to understand why Scala runtime does not complain while i try to cast one subclass into another. And how do i make scala to complain.

I have following inheritance in my application

```
trait I {
val i: String
}

trait K extends I {
val k: String
}

case class S(override val i:String, override val k: String, val s: String) extends K

case class M(override val i: String, val m: String) extends I
```

As per my understanding following method call should have thrown a class cast exception. But it works perfectly fine. listM holds list of S. And i am able to create instance of MakeM such that its member contains List of S instead of List of M. This is very confusing. How does this work? Is scala being smart in converting one subclass into another subclass. How do i enforce scala to complain when sub classes are being casted into one another.

```
case class MakeM(val data:String, val list: Seq[M])


object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val listOfS = Some(List(S("i1", "k1", "s1"), S("i2", "k2", "s2")))
    val listOfM:Seq[M] = listOfS.get.asInstanceOf[Seq[M]] //this works , why?
    val m1 = MakeM("some data", listOfM); //this works. why?
    //val m2 = MakeM("some data", listOfS.get); //this fails
    println(s"$m1");
  }

}
```

**Actual Output**

```
MakeM(some data,List(S(i1,k1,s1), S(i2,k2,s2)))
```

**Expected Output**

```
 Class Cast exception.
```

Comment: @jwvh my bad i wrote a pseudo code. I have updated it to compilable and runnable code. Kindly revert the negative point so the question gets rightful attention.

Comment: This seems like a lot more code than needed to explain the question. Can it be reduced to a minimal example?

Comment: @konquestor, I'll withdraw my comment since you've fixed the posted code (thank you), but I didn't down-vote the question so I can't reverse that.

Comment: @ChrisMartin i have shortened the code. can you help me understand whats going on?

Comment: Sorry misread the question. If the code works in runtime, try accessing `list(0).m` or even just `list(0)` in the `MakeM` class. Maybe the cast works because it only checks the list class itself and not inner-elements; `List` inherits from `Seq`

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089390/why-asinstanceof-doesnt-throw-a-classcastexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204473/why-does-asinstanceof-sometimes-throw-and-sometimes-not and others like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153502/why-does-1-asinstanceoft-not-throw-classcastexception

Answer (score 2):

Much of what doesn't compile is a violation of the type system. An example is your line of code with the `this fails` comment.  It fails due to a type mismatch.  Using `asInstanceOf[]` overrides the type system.

```
"word".asInstanceOf[Float]  // this compiles, but it won't run
```

In your code, if you were to do something like this...

```
m1.list.head.m  // this compiles because you told the compiler m1 is type MakeM
```

...it will throw a runtime error because `m1` isn't *really* type `MakeM`.  We learn that only at runtime because you told the compiler to pretend otherwise.

This runs `println(s"$m1")` (Scala code doesn't need the semicolon) because the underlying `toString` method doesn't impact the type inconsistency.

It sounds like you want the compiler to disallow unsafe casting, but by making the cast you are taking away the compiler's main safety-detector.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured a bit out, it only checks the List, not List[insideType]. So it works for doing List.asInstance(Seq[Anytype]) because Seq works for List. 
However, if you want to test to the inside type level, it will gives you cast exception.

```
val listTemp:Seq[K] = listOfS.get.asInstanceOf[Seq[K]]
val listTemp2:Seq[Double] = listOfS.get.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]
println(listTemp(1)) //S(i2,k2,s2)
println(listTemp(1).k) //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: S cannot be cast to K
println(listTemp2.isInstanceOf[Seq[S]]) // true, Seq[Double] is instance of Seq[S], only checks Seq
```

Please refer to this post, it has some similar problem may interest you:
[Scala isInstanceOf and type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900143/scala-isinstanceof-and-type-erasure)

"""

```
scala> val l = List("foo")
l: List[String] = List(foo)

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[String]]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
<console>:9: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type List[String] cannot also be a List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) (but still might match its erasure)
              l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
                            ^
res1: Boolean = true
```

"""